# need to apply dynamic app icon from web in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, appicon

We need to set up an alternative app icon form API, From API we get an image with user initials.

We already set up one alternative app icon code on the iOS side with static icon.

Now the plan is load image from the web and replaces the static icon. 
Problem is bundle file is read-only mode and we need to setup icon over there.

is there any way to load an app icon from the web?

Thanks

Comment: All alternate icons must be included in the bundle when you submit it to the App Store.  You cannot add a new icon without submitting a new version for App Store review.

Comment: yes, So there is no way to load an icon from web API